# convert module.export to es6

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I am trying to convert this function to es6 sintax:

```
module.exports = function( key, fieldID ) {
    var self = this;
    self.Elements = function() {
        this.cache = {
            $btn: jQuery( '#dav' + key + '_button' ),
            $apiField: jQuery( '#dav' + key ),
            $apiUrl: jQuery( '#dav' + fieldID ),
        };
    };
};
```

Should start like this:

```
export default ( key, fieldID ) => {
        const self = this;
        self.Elements = function() {...
```

What is the correct way to convert this module to es6?

Comment: Your `const self = this` statement is going to behave differently when you switch to an arrow func.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following should work:

```js
export default function(key, fieldID) {
  var self = this;
  self.Elements = function() {
    this.cache = {
      $btn: jQuery('#dav' + key + '_button'),
      $apiField: jQuery('#dav' + key),
      $apiUrl: jQuery('#dav' + fieldID),
    };
  };
}
```